# jQuery .is(":focus") doesn't recognize focus on checkbox in browsers other than IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox and a text input. Here's how it works: The cursor goes to the text input when the checkbox is checked. When the text input loses focus, I look to see whether the text input value is empty. If it is, I uncheck the checkbox.

Problem is when it loses focus because I click on the checkbox a second time... The checkbox unchecks and then is checked again, so I can't uncheck it.

I fix this by looking to see if the new focused element is the checkbox. If it isn't, I proceed as normal. This works perfectly in IE, but not in the other browsers I've tested (Chrome, Firefox, Safari).

Anyone have any ideas how to get this to work? Or maybe a different solution?

My actual problem with blur function: http://jsfiddle.net/4mJuU/5/ (only works in IE)

Simple focus with just a text input http://jsfiddle.net/HWFHv/2/ (works)

Simple focus with just a checkbox http://jsfiddle.net/sXqcG/1/ (doesn't work in Chrome/Safari)

```
$('#cbx').live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#txt').focus();
    }
    else {
        $('#txt').val('');
    }
});
$('#txt').live('blur', function(event) {
    //var doesCbxHaveFocus = document.activeElement.id == 'cbx';
    var doesCbxHaveFocus = $('#cbx').is(':focus');
    console.log(doesCbxHaveFocus);
    if (!doesCbxHaveFocus) {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $('#cbx').prop('checked', false);
        }
        else {
            $('#cbx').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Both jsfiddles work for me on latest FF

Comment: Not seeing a problem with the fiddles here either.

Comment: @elclanrs you are right, however it still doesn't work in my actual problem, where I am checking .is(':focus') from the blur function of text input.

Comment: Have you considered using the change event of the controls instead?

Comment: @Emyr in what way do you mean? I don't want the checkbox to be unchecked when the text input is empty and still has focus. I only want that to be evaluated when the text input has lost focus.

Answer (score 1):

may be blur-event fires before focus on checkbox. So when blur-handler executes focus is not happened yet, that's why .is(':focus') does not work.
You can try smth like

```
setTimeout(onBlurFunc, 10);
```

or find better workaround, but problem lies here.
onBlurFunc here is the function you attached to text-inp blur-event